# Did Alicia really wear a wedding scarf at the end of Senjou no Valkyria (Valkyria Chronicles)?

Tags: valkyria-chronicles

I've found this image by coincidence, but it immediately attracted my attention because I never saw such a scene in the anime.

[image]

Concerning the drawing style/animation (from the looks of it I doubt it's fan-made, it seems to be more like a screenshot), the sunset, Welkin's clothes (he wears them very rarely and if I remember correctly, he wears them only at the very end of the anime) and progression of the story (they end up together in the last episode (26)), this image has to be from the very end of the anime, but I couldn't find anything like it.

I've also watched it on different websites, but they all end with Alicia and Welkin holding hands in the sunset on a hill in front of their village.

Where is this screenshot from? Does that scene really happen in the anime or is it from the game?

Comment: Are you trying to ask if this picture is from fan-made material or not?

Comment: It's been a while so I don't remember exactly what she was wearing in that final scene. But it's implied that they get married shortly after. The game takes it a bit further and you get to see their daughter.

Comment: @Mysticial however to my knowledge from when last i played it you don't see their wedding.

Comment: @Maroon I'm already (almost) sure that this picture isn't fan-made since the animation/drawing-style is exactly the same as the one from the anime.  And it's quite obvious that this is a screenshot if you consider the quality (a bit blurred).

Comment: @Eti2d1: got it. The last line threw me off when I was reading this yesterday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That picture of Alicia and Welkin is from ***OVA 9***, or the epilogue from the story.

It's a screenshot of this OVA where the summery can be found on the official wikia page from Valkyria Chronicles [here](http://valkyria.wikia.com/wiki/Valkyria_Chronicles_Anime)

It's marked as episode #35 at the bottem of the page